# Rails Heroku Postgres JavaScript Button action only works on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-performance, heroku-postgres

I have a one page lorem ipsum generator Rails App running 4.0.2, Ruby 2.1.0.  The App works fine in development however after being deployed on Heroku there's an issue with the button click not working on the first click.  In development it can handle queries of 20+ but in production it seems to be getting stuck on anything higher than 5 paragraphs.

The button action renders the submit.js.erb with a 200 status on each failed click until it eventually works with additional clicks.  Since it works fine in development, I was thinking it could be a Postgres query issue with how the model call is structured.

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated.  The App is currently deployed at:

http://blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com/

Form on index.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag "/submit", remote: true do %>
    <div class="form">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <div class="field">
            <td><p class="question">HOW MANY PARAGRAPHS?</p></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag :paragraph_count, 1, {style: "width: 40px;", maxvalue: "10" } %></td>
            </div>
    <div class="actions">
          <%= submit_tag "Serenity Now", class: "btn btn-custom btn-lg", id: "buttnow" %>
        </div>
```

routes.rb file

```
      resources :homes
      root to: 'homes#index'
      post '/submit', to: 'homes#submit'
      resources :paragraphs
```

controller.rb file

```
      def submit
        limit = params[:paragraph_count].to_i
        @paragraphs = Paragraph.pluck(:description).shuffle[0...limit]

        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end
```

submit.js.erb file

```
    $('#koanz').html("<p><%= @paragraphs.join('</p><p>').html_safe %></p>").show();
```

Heroku logs after multiple click

```
            2014-02-27T03:25:45.933357+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:45 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.935086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.935086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.935086+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.933357+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:45 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.935086+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.956141+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 13.4ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.955920+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.955920+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:45.956141+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 13.4ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:46.017862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=c235c25b-ebb6-432f-8c82-2eb10c435678 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=90ms status=200 bytes=3085
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.061798+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:48 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.061798+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:48 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.063252+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.063252+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.063252+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.069377+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.069588+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.069377+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.063497+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:48.069588+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.138997+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:49 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.143518+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.157302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=1b726361-d376-4924-ac27-6d368ebdf631 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=2431
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.138997+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:49 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.143518+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.143518+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.143518+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.153074+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.153074+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.153222+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:49.153222+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.279112+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:50 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.302745+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:50 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.308782+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.365665+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.342596+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.342934+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.342811+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.435740+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 69.1ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.434368+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 69.1ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:50.433489+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.164082+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.164082+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.165062+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.165062+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.165062+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.185743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=840bd593-2bb9-4126-907c-f09443a10695 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=200 bytes=3025
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.179108+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.179067+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.170996+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.178856+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.178678+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.533809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=57abc2d7-5e73-4bf2-a875-1347fa37ed32 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=2167
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.519012+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.521359+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.522698+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.523888+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.523972+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.524046+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.531096+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.531385+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.531385+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.531096+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.867868+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.867868+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:51 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.879393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=76c566ff-400a-40fa-8b01-c1e988cfc132 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=2788
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.869165+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.869165+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.869165+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.869165+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.879542+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.6ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.879542+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.879542+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.6ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:51.879542+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.012890+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:52 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.012890+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/submit" for 50.149.115.166 at 2014-02-27 03:25:52 +0000
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.014468+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.014468+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#submit as JS
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.014468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.014468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "paragraph_count"=>"5"}
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.018213+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.018173+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/submit.js.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.018492+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:52.018415+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
    2014-02-27T03:25:37.884064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=blooming-refuge-1066.herokuapp.com request_id=9920cd7f-26f9-4805-9741-569786279471 fwd="50.149.115.166" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=101ms status=200 bytes=6213
```

Answer (score 0):

this kind of error often happens when you load the same javascript file more than once.  Make sure jquery_ujs and jquery only load once.

Comment: The loading of JS files looks okay.  In addition, the performance of the button click is directly correlated to the size of the input.  30 paragraphs in development takes 1 sec, whereas in production I can't even get a response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was causing a double submit on random occurrences was that a few of the production paragraphs contained special character quotes and a few extra return white spaces. These caused the javascript to break in submit.js.erb.  To resolve this submit.js.erb was altered.

```
    $('#koanz').html("<p><%= @paragraphs.map{|x| html_escape(x.gsub(/\n/, ''))}.join('</p><p>').html_safe %></p>").show();
```